# Debugging program running another program

Tags: c, gdb

I wrote a shell in C. There are some problems while running some programs on it.How can I run a program on a shell while debugging the shell in the gdb?

Comment: One Should put some efforts before posting a question here.

Answer (score 1):

First use `-g` option to compile with debugging flags, for use with `gdb`.

Then run.

```
gdb shellapp
...
run someapps
...
```

For a quick reading [How to Debug C Program using gdb in 6 Simple Steps](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/) and [GDB Tutorial](http://oucsace.cs.ohiou.edu/~bhumphre/gdb.html)

Or do you mean [run a program in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338895/1606345)?

Comment: It need to compiler program using `-g`

Comment: Hi Grijesh, thanks for the edit ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can attach by gdb to already running shell process from another console. This way your shell output will not interfere with gdb output and you can run programs in shell as usual.

1. Run your implementation of shell in 1st console window
2. Open 2nd console and find pid number of already running shell using `ps` command
3. Start `gdb` in 2nd console and [attach](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Attach.html#Attach) to shell using it's pid number like this:

   :~$ gdb -q
   (gdb) attach 3479
   Attaching to process 3479
4. Now you can set breakpoints and continue shell execution:

   (gdb) b SomeFunction
   (gdb) c
   Continuing.

From this point you have 2 consoles:

- the one where your shell is running
- and the second where `gdb` runs attached to shell

You can use shell as usual: run other programs on it or do whatever else. And at the same time you can observe shell execution in 2nd console inside `gdb`. The point is that output of these 2 processes are separated from each other which would be impossible if you run shell directly inside gdb in just one console.

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying...explain a bit more..

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan, I mean that it's hard to debug interactive shell from the same console where gdb runs, because gdb itself is interactive. Output from both gdb and shell will mix up and it makes difficulties during debug.

Comment: Please explain. This is what I need.

Comment: @ks1322 Oh! get your point now, and you are correct If OP already don't know how to use GDB ..your point is valid.