# What is the purpose of the "&" sign when you run a .py file via command shell?

Tags: python, shell

I read a tutorial about how to set up a chat program using client-server model here, http://code.activestate.com/recipes/531824-chat-server-client-using-selectselect/

they have a .py file called "chatserver.py" and ran it in linux-like command shell with extra option:

```
$ python chatserver.py &
```

what is the purpose of the "&" sign there?

(apology, first time asker)

Comment: It is run in background.

Comment: Googling for "linux command line & at the end" immediately yields: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean

Comment: This has nothing to do with python

Comment: apology, I thought it is python-only option. Should have googled about linux commands first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is run in background.

The terminal returns the focus to the user and you can run another command. It is the same for any command, not only python. See [this](http://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html).

Comment: The question has already been marked as a duplicate and adding an answer which most of the content is in an external link is also not a great deal of use

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The question has been marked as a duplicate while I was writting the answer, sorry.

Comment: If there is something in the link not in the dupe add it to your answer, a link can die any time