# Linux: run in subshell

Tags: linux, bash, nohup, subshell

I want to start a long-running process from a script that then exits, but I'm getting nowhere. Here's my most simple test. With each run, the console is blocked for 5 seconds.

```
// Create script
me@mine:~/workspace/bin$ cat > test.sh
sleep 5
// Verify script
me@mine:~/workspace/bin$ cat test.sh
sleep 5
// Make executable
me@mine:~/workspace/bin$ chmod 777 test.sh
// Expect to wait
me@mine:~/workspace/bin$ ./test.sh
// Expect to return, still waits
me@mine:~/workspace/bin$ ./test.sh ?
// Ditto
me@mine:~/workspace/bin$ nohup ./test.sh ?
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
me@mine:~/workspace/bin$
```

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 64,
GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

I'm a Linux noob, and I'm sure I'm not getting something. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ampersand: `nohup ./test.sh &`

Comment: Yeah. It helps to use the correct character. Seriously, thanks for pointing that out. <shamed/>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script is waiting for something. Paste your script in here.

Comment: How is that different from the `chomd` then execute in the original question, and how will that put `test.sh` in the background?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do it, my go-to way is by put an ampersand `&` at the end of the line.

More ways are found with [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/137319/put-a-task-to-the-background-with-bash)

More explanation on the ampersand method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean)