# Second QueryParam is not accepting for Restfull API in Java

Tags: java, jersey, query-string

I have an API where it accepts 4 `Queryparams`. Here the problem is, it is accepting only first `QueryParam` and not accepting other `QueryParams`

Sample `Curl`:

```
1) curl -vk -X GET http://localhost:8080/sample-application/employee?empname=sat&empId=3438&designation=developer
```

Here its not accepting `empId` & `designation` i.e in the `O/P` printing `null` values

```
2) curl -vk -X GET http://localhost:8080/sample-application/employee?empId=3438&empname=sat&designation=developer
```

Here its not accepting `empname` & `designation` i.e in the `O/P` printing `null` values

```
3) curl -vk -X GET http://localhost:8080/sample-application/employee?designation=developer&empname=sat&empId=3438
```

Here its not accepting `empname` & `empId` i.e in the `O/P` printing `null` values

Here is my `code`

```
 @Path("/employee")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public class EmployeeRS {

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeRS.class);

 @GET
 @ApiOperation(value = "Get Employee Details", response = Employee.class)
 public Response getEmployee(
        @ApiParam(value = "Employee Name", required = false) @QueryParam(value = "empname") final String empname,
        @ApiParam(value = "Employee Id", required = false) @QueryParam("empId") String empId,
        @ApiParam(value = "Designation", required = false) @QueryParam("designation") String designation) {

        logger.info("Get Employee for empname:{}, empId:{}, designation:{}",
                empname, empId, designation);
        //Functionality to get Data
 }
}
```

Comment: add double quotation in your curl url else it will not take the value after the &. That's why it's taking only one parameter.

Comment: [The `&` has a special meaning in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13338870/2587435), that's why it stops after the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem, the issue is with the `curl` command. In order to consider more than 1 `Query Param`, we have to add quotes (" or ') just before `URL` i.e `http` and at the end of URL. So we have to place `URL` between the quotes.

```
curl -vk -X GET "http://localhost:8080/sample-application/employee?empId=3438&empname=sat&designation=developer"
```