# Triggering a customized plan in bamboo with cURL command

Tags: curl

I am using the below command to trigger a cudtomized plan where it is running fine with only one variable

curl -XPOST -u username:passwd https://bamboo-starterkit.abc.com/rest/api/latest/queue/BUILDKEY?bamboo.variable.var_name1=etcetc

But the command fails to run successful when there are more variables. which we are providing in curl:

curl -XPOST -u username:passwd https://bamboo-starterkit.abc.com/rest/api/latest/queue/BUILDKEY?bamboo.variable.var_name1=var1&bamboo.variable.var_name2=var2-v

Answer (score 2):

The `&` character in your url putting this the curl [command into background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean). Wrap the url with quotes to resolve it.

```
curl -XPOST -u username:passwd "https://bamboo-starterkit.abc.com/rest/api/latest/queue/BUILDKEY?bamboo.variable.var_name1=var1&bamboo.variable.var_name2=var2-v"
```