# snakemake always report " MissingOutputException in line 44, Missing files after 5 seconds:

Tags: pipeline, snakemake, rna-seq

I always get the same error report in my RNAs-seq pipeline by snakemake:

```
MissingOutputException in line 44 of /root/s/r/snakemake/my_rnaseq_data/Snakefile:
Missing files after 5 seconds:
03_align/wt2.bam
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
```

Here is my Snakefile:

```
SBT=["wt1","wt2","epcr1","epcr2"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("02_clean/{nico}_1.paired.fq", nico=SBT),
        expand("02_clean/{nico}_2.paired.fq", nico=SBT),
        expand("03_align/{nico}.bam", nico=SBT)

rule trim:
    input:
        "01_raw/{nico}_1.fastq",
        "01_raw/{nico}_2.fastq"
    output:
        "02_clean/{nico}_1.paired.fq.gz",
        "02_clean/{nico}_1.unpaired.fq.gz",
        "02_clean/{nico}_2.paired.fq.gz",
        "02_clean/{nico}_2.unpaired.fq.gz",
    shell:
        "java -jar /software/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar PE -threads 16 {input[0]} {input[1]} {output[0]} {output[1]} {output[2]} {output[3]} ILLUMINACLIP:/software/Trimmomatic-0.36/adapters/TruSeq3-PE-2.fa:2:30:10 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36 &"

rule gzip:
    input:
        "02_clean/{nico}_1.paired.fq.gz",
        "02_clean/{nico}_2.paired.fq.gz"
    output:
        "02_clean/{nico}_1.paired.fq",
        "02_clean/{nico}_2.paired.fq"
    run:
        shell("gzip -d {input[0]} > {output[0]}")
        shell("gzip -d {input[1]} > {output[1]}")

rule map:
    input:
        "02_clean/{nico}_1.paired.fq",
        "02_clean/{nico}_2.paired.fq"
    output:
        "03_align/{nico}.sam"
    log:
        "logs/map/{nico}.log"
    threads: 40
    shell:
        "hisat2 -p 20 --dta -x /root/s/r/p/A_th/WT-Al_VS_WT-CK/index/tair10 -1 {input[0]} -2 {input[1]} -S {output} >{log} 2>&1 &"

rule sort2bam:
    input:
        "03_align/{nico}.sam"
    output:
        "03_align/{nico}.bam"
    threads:30
    shell:
        "samtools sort -@ 20 -m 20G -o {output} {input} &"
```

everything is fine until I add "rule sort2bam" part.

When I dry-run ,it goes fine. But when I execute it,it report error as the question describe. And Surprisely it run the task where it report it stuck in the background.But it always run the one task.like these:

```
rule sort2bam:
    input: 03_align/epcr1.sam
    output: 03_align/epcr1.bam
    jobid: 11
    wildcards: nico=epcr1

Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 45 of /root/s/r/snakemake/my_rnaseq_data/Snakefile:
Missing files after 5 seconds:
03_align/epcr1.bam
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

```
[Sat Apr 27 06:10:22 2019]
rule sort2bam:
    input: 03_align/wt1.sam
    output: 03_align/wt1.bam
    jobid: 9
    wildcards: nico=wt1

Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 45 of /root/s/r/snakemake/my_rnaseq_data/Snakefile:
Missing files after 5 seconds:
03_align/wt1.bam
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

```
[Sat Apr 27 06:23:13 2019]
rule sort2bam:
    input: 03_align/wt2.sam
    output: 03_align/wt2.bam
    jobid: 6
    wildcards: nico=wt2

Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 44 of /root/s/r/snakemake/my_rnaseq_data/Snakefile:
Missing files after 5 seconds:
03_align/wt2.bam
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code? Any ideals? Thanks in advance!

Comment: and the line 44 is "rule sort2bam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you figured out, `&` is the problem. Control operator `&` makes your command run in the background in a subshell, and this leads snakemake to think that job is complete when in fact it is not. In your case, its usage doesn't appear to be required.

From `man bash` on usage of `&` (stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338895/3998252)):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator **&**, the shell
>   executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does
>   not wait for the command to finish,  and
>          the  return status is 0.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to solve, but I don't know why it works!
Just delete the '&' in

```
samtools sort -@ 20 -m 20G -o {output} {input} &
```