# Python Running with Alias

Tags: python, linux, shell, process

So I'm trying to run a python with this syntax that i found in internet.

```
python test.py test&
```

I'm wondering what does the `test&` mean?.

When i just run `python test.py`
and `ps aux | grep python` the output is.

```
root    19858  0.0  0.3  15148  6164 pts/1    S    23:07   0:00 python test.py
```

And when you run `python test.py test&`
The output now in `ps aux | grep python` is

```
root    19858  0.0  0.3  15148  6164 pts/1    S    23:07   0:00 python test.py test
```

I know the last part starting from `python` is command but can you explain further.

Comment: `test&` is actually two things:  `test` and `&`.  The `test` potion is an argument to your python script, available in `sys.argv`.  The `&` part is something most Unix shells will treat as an indication to run the process in background.

Comment: oh so it's not like an alias for a running process?

Comment: @NikkoBobier :  See [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=7ExfDfcLZXsC&lpg=PA547&ots=4RbavLVnFS&dq=shell%20separate%20commands&pg=PA547#v=onepage&q=shell%20separate%20commands&f=false) for the shell syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you write command in a shell each word is take as a parameter

- parameter 0 : `python` means that you use the python command
- parameter 1 : `test.py` the first parameter given to the command parameter so in your script you cant get the string `test.py` by using `sys.argv[0]`
- parameter 2 : `test` the second parameter given to the command parameter so in your script you cant get the string `test` by using `sys.argv[1]`

The & symbol is a bash character which mean run in background the previous command so your script will run but you still get an access on your terminal.

Comment: The & originated with the Unix Bourne Shell, sh. It was later adopted by csh. bash is a descendant of sh which extended the syntax and added some csh-like features. Another sh descendant is ksh. There are csh descendants as well, such as tcsh. OP may be using any one of these. OP may be using `bash`, or may be using any one of the other shells I listed above.

Comment: OP tagges the post as _shell_, which, without any other shell-related tag, is supposed to mean POSIX shell.

Answer (score 1):

See the following: 
[What does "&" at the end of a linux command mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean)

It means its running in the background.

Comment: according to your link provided, it's means that i can run another process as long as i want. right?

Comment: Yes, also look for "nohup" if you want to redirect your input/output of your script.