# How to run child_process.exec correctly on an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, child-process

There is a server, that I have an access to, but do not have ownership on. It serves a node js / express application on a default port 3000. There are several scripts, that are usually run either manually from the terminal or by cron job. What I want to do is to have a button on the client-side and make an ajax request to a certain route and execute a node js command with inline arguments. For example:

`node script.js 123`

All routes are set and working. I have a `CliController` file that handles requests and has to run the command above. Currently I am using the following code:

```
cp.exec(`node script.js ${ip}`, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
 });
```

The `script.js` file is in root folder of the project, but the project itself was built by using `express-generator` and is being served using `node bin/www` command. There is a service/process on the server that runs `nodemon` to restart this project if it fails as well. Therefore I do not have access to output of that particular process.

If I run the command above in the terminal (from the root folder of the project, to be precise), it works fine and I see the output of the script. But if I press the button on the webpage to make a request, I am pretty sure that the script does not execute, because it has to make an update to database and I do not see any changes. I also tried to use `child_process.spawn` and `child_process.fork` and failed to get it working.

I also tried to kill `nodemon` and quickly start the project again to the see console output. If I do this, everything works.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Well, you said it all: you don't have access to the server. You won't be able to run any kind of shell command from an api call. Or if you find a way, this would mean the server is dangerously open to remote shell attacks.

Comment: @NVRM But I can connect to server using SSH as root and I am able to run node commands in the terminal.  Is it not enough?

Comment: Alright, then yes you will find a way. I misunderstood. Maybe simply add `&` at the end of your command, to detach the execution. Try `node script.js ${ip} &`, see what it does. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean

Comment: Thank you so much, @NVRM , it worked! I previously searched for child processes in docs, but did not know about detaching. Also, wanted to upvote your comment, but for some reason  I do not see the option to upvote the comment yet.  Is it possible for you to answer this question so I can accept it as the answer? If it's not possible, I will answer myself, but will quote your comment.

Comment: Made that. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges for infos about points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process invoked may be in a blocking state, hence the parent script is simply waiting for the children process to terminate, or return something.

We can avoid this behaviour right into the shell command, by adding `&` (ampersand control operator) at the end.

This makes a command running in the background. (Notice, you can still control the children(s) process using the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier)'s and [POSIX signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)), *this is another subject*, but very related and you might find it very handy pretty soon).

Also notice that killing/stopping the parent script will also kill the children(s). This can be avoided using `nohup`.

This is not linked to JavaScript or node.js, but to `bash`, and can be used with anything in the shell.

```
cp.exec(`node script.js ${ip} &`, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
 });
```

[Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)