# ROS/Linux: What exactly does '&' in the linux terminal?

Tags: terminal, ros

I am working with ROS. And for starting ros-packages you need to have the ROS Master run in the background. Now when I want to start the ROS-package rviz, instead of opening two terminals:
**Terminal1:**

```
$ roscore
```

**Terminal2:**

```
$ rviz
```

I can do the follwing in one Terminal:

```
$ roscore& rviz
```

But what exactly is happening here? Because when I end that terminal with `Str+C` it only closes rivz, but roscore is kept running in the background? Why and how can I close it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/how-to-terminate-a-background-process over on Unix.SE

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean/13338895#13338895

Comment: you are right thank you!

Answer (score 2):

in case using single & the left side will run in the background, while the right side will run normally in the terminal.

Now to close the first process you need to find PID (Process ID) and do the termination command, so first of all you need to find PID and you can use pgrep (in your case PROCESS_NAME can be roscore):

```
pgrep -f PROCESS_NAME
```

Now to kill the process you can easily do:

```
kill -9 PID_HERE
```

Or you can do it by single command:

```
pgrep -f PROCESS_NAME | xargs kill -9
```