# How to excape '&' in a sh()-call in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

I want to call curl on a webpage with get parameters from the jenkins-groovy-script via sh:

```
sh("curl http://example.com/page.cgi?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c")
```

But the command is split at the '&' and in the output log of jenkins there is something like:

```
+ param3=c
+ curl http://example.com/page.cgi?param1=a
+ param2=b
```

Of course the call to the web server only contains the first parameter.

I tried already with different kind of escaping but without success.

How can I make the call including all the parameters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @tripleee The answer from @ KamilCuk solved my problem. In the answer provided by you I miss the information about the meaning of '&' in shell.

Comment: I'll be more than happy to add https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean to the list of duplicates if you accept the duplicate nomination.

Comment: @tripleee although the question handles the problem of the meaning of '&' in the shell I don't see this as a duplicate. My problem was based of the behavior of the '&' inside a command parameter. Your second suggestion is focused on the & at the ending and therefore I think I wouldn't have found the solution there.

Comment: Either you should accept that this is a shell metacharacter and that metacharacters need to be escaped or quoted; or you genuinely care what it means. You seem to be moving the goalposts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in the command line, you have to quote it or escape it. Research quoting and escaping in `sh` shell.

Try:

```
sh("curl 'http://example.com/page.cgi?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c'")
sh('curl "http://example.com/page.cgi?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c"')
sh("curl http://example.com/page.cgi?param1=a\\&param2=b&param3=c")
sh("curl \"http://example.com/page.cgi?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c\"")
```

`&` in shell means to run something in the background, like `sleep 10 & wait`.