# Remove a file has the same name with folder after using tar

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I created a script to find files, move them to a folder, compress this folder using `tar`. Then delete original folder. But after running the script, the folder was removed but a file having same name with the folder was created. I tried to run one by one command, it's OK. There is not this file. I added `rm` command in the script to remove it but not working.
I don't know why this file was create.

My script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/tuan/testrm/9/
mkdir compressdir
sudo find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print | xargs -I {} mv {} compressdir > /dev/null 2>&1 &
tar -cvzf compresslog.tar.gz --remove-files compressdir
mv compresslog.tar.gz compresslog-`date +"%d%m%Y"`.tar.gz
rm -rf compressdir
```

[image: image show]

I want to know why this file was create and how to prevent this happen.

Comment: Please format your script in a [readable way](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove  `&` at the end of `sudo find` line, and it will works.

Because of [The **`&`** makes the command run in the background.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean)

Root cause: the `sudo find` command line and `tar -> mv -> rm` run at synchronized.

If you had checked the file *compresslog.tar.gz* which the script generated, you will found that it was null or error, and the *compress* file contain the same content with someone file which you `find`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works. I used $ it because I want it run in the background. I'll try another way.

Comment: Welcome, you could try this: `{ command 1; command 2; } &` run the multiple commands at backgroud.