# When running two tail commands in background, second tail is not working

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, background-process, io-redirection

I am trying to run a process in remote machine and `tail` its stdout and stderr to my local machine.

But for some unknown reason, this command is tailing only stdout.

```
ssh <remote> 'tail /tmp/tmp.gLxtGhFRts/.stdout & tail /tmp/tmp.gLxtGhFRts/.stderr >&2 &'
---contents of stdout---
```

If I remove the trailing ampersand, both tails are working as expected.

```
ssh <remote> 'tail /tmp/tmp.gLxtGhFRts/.stdout & tail /tmp/tmp.gLxtGhFRts/.stderr >&2'
---contents of stdout---
---contents of stderr---
```

If I remove the trailing redirection, both tails are working as expected.

```
ssh <remote> 'tail /tmp/tmp.gLxtGhFRts/.stdout & tail /tmp/tmp.gLxtGhFRts/.stderr &'
---contents of stdout---
---contents of stderr---
```

Why is adding an ampersand(`&`) or redirection(`>&2`) at the end suppressing the second command? Can someone please explain this behaviour?

**EDIT:**

I tested the same thing with `head` and `cat`. The same behavior is seen with them also.

I tested the same thing with different files. The same behavior is seen with them also.

I `ssh`ed the remote and then tried all these combinations. All are working as expected. So I think the issue is with `ssh`.

**EDIT:**

I tried adding `wait` at the very end. And now it is working as expected.

But AFAIK, `ssh` waits until its stdin, stdout and stderr pipes close. So I'm not understanding why we need an explicit `wait`. Also, stdout is tailing fine without wait. So I still need an explanation.

---

EDIT: these all work as expected:

```
ssh remote 'cat /etc/hosts >&2'
ssh remote 'cat /etc/hosts &'
ssh remote 'cat /etc/hosts >&1 &'
```

but this produces no output:

```
ssh remote 'cat /etc/hosts >&2 &'
```

Why does that last one produce no output?

Comment: this answers your doubts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean

Comment: I edited the question to provide a more concise [mcve].

Comment: If you run the command in the background, the shell exits immediately and the SSH connection closes.

Comment: @Barmar Shell exists immediately. But ssh connection stays on till all pipes are closed AFAIK. For example, `ssh remote 'cat /etc/hosts &'` runs fine.